# What's the best way to level up a Brave Burst?

Tags: android, brave-frontier

When I'm going to fuse a unit, some units used as **ingredient** can upgrade the Brave Burst skill of the **Base** unit.

But what's the best way to do this upgrade? Fuse each unit separately or get 5 ingredient units and fuse it together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://bravefrontierglobal.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:How_to_increase_BRAVE_BURST'S_level%3F):

> > During fusing, each unit with the same type of Brave Burst used in the fusion has a small chance to increase the base unit's Brave Burst
> >     level. There are 3 types so far:
>
> Offensive Brave Bursts (damage single or everyone) Healing Brave
>   Bursts Stat boosting Brave Bursts, which I call Support (e.g.,
>   increase ATK, crit, etc.) Let's say you have a Fire God Vargas with
>   Brave Burst level 1. His BB is an offensive type, since it inflicts
>   damage. If you fuse 5x Metal Gods into him, he has ZERO chance to
>   increase his BB levels because the Metal Gods are not of the same type
>   of Brave Burst (they actually have no Brave Burst). Now let's say that
>   you fuse 5x Pikeman Lances. Since Pikeman Lance does have an offensive
>   Brave Burst, then there is a chance that Vargas' BB level will
>   increase, multiple times even. Personally,I've gone from 1 to 4 during
>   a single fuse session.
>
> What I don't know:
>
> Does the element of the fused unit matter for increased chances of BB
>   level up? I think so, but not confirmed. I've seen 3 BB level
>   increases from a single fuse using slimes  Does the chance diminish as
>   the Brave Burst level gets higher? Does the rarity of the unit being
>   consumed matter? Does the level of the unit being consumed matter?
>   Confirmed:
>
> ELEMENT of fused unit  matter a little for increasing the chances of
>   BB level up. The rarity of unit being consumed only matter a little.
>   Level of unit being consume doesnt matter Fusing the same unit ( Great
>   Sage Mimir + Sage Mimir ) increases the chance of BB leveling up.
>
> Some tips:
>
> Evolving a unit resets its Brave Burst back half of the previous Brave
>   Burst level (For example, a Vargas with Brave Burst level 10, it will
>   become level 5 when he evolved into Burning Vargas). And if the level
>   is at the odd number (Example : 9) it will be halved into lower half
>   (into level 4). Don't focus on leveling Brave Burst until the unit has
>   reached its maximum evolution. Note that future updates may introduce
>   higher levels of evolution for specific units! If you're going to
>   focus on leveling Brave Burst, start early when it's cheap! Save those
>   high-XP fuse unit (e.g., Metal Kings) for after you've hit BB Lvl. 10.
>   Use the weekend to amass zel from the Weekend dungeon. You're gonna
>   need a lot of money!

It seems to me that the fusion of 5 ingredient units and fusing them together will be the best bet. Because you are doing it in bulk the exp will be far greater than just slowly leveling each unit individually.